# Standard way of developing a node module using Coffeescript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Is there a recommended way of developing a node module if I want to write it in Coffeescript, but don't want to force the module's users to require the `coffee-script` module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your CoffeeScript codes in the `src` folder and the compiled JavaScript codes in `lib` folder.

Then in your `package.json` file, declare `main` to be the js file in the `lib` folder. Then the users of your package will require the js file instead of the coffee file.

You may take @TrevorBurnham's [repository](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) as an example.

Comment: It kind of feels weird committing compiled code, but I guess I'm going to try that.

Comment: Is the git repository linked to npm? Because if it isn't, I could generate the lib folder just before npm publish and delete it after.

Comment: @MarcelM. It's not. BTW, you can use .gitignore to ignore the `lib` folder instead of delete it.

Comment: The example repository is gone, and the recommended replacement doesn't seem to use coffeescript.

Answer (score 8):

I ended with only a `src` folder on my git repository; a `.gitignore` file with an line for `lib`; and an empty `.npmignore` file. The empty `.npmignore` file is needed because if it's not on your module, your `.gitignore` is used instead.

I just added a `Cakefile` with a task to build my `src` directory using `coffee --compile --output lib/ src/` and a `pretest` and `prepublish` task to `package.json` to build before testing and publishing.

`"scripts": {
    "pretest": "cake build",
    "prepublish": "cake build",
  }`

This solution keeps my git repository clean (without compiled code), but adds my javascript code to lib when publishing to npm.

Comment: Note: this doesn't (yet) work for "npm install reaktivo/zootool". Someone might want to do something similar if they forked your repo and were waiting for you to take their patch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just getting started with CoffeeScript, but I'd suggest the following:

1. Store your CoffeeScript code in `src/*.coffee`,
2. Write a `main.js` in the project's root that NPM will catch, and have it simply do something like `require('coffee-script'); require('./src/my_lib.coffee')`.

There. You never, ever compile your code; it's all handled transparently. You don't check compiled code into git, nor do you publish superfluous compiled JavaScript alongside the uncompiled CoffeeScript to NPM.

**Edit:**
In more recent versions coffee-scirpt, you should `require('coffee-script/register');`

Comment: Feels like making `coffee-script` a requirement for a module you are not developing is not the best idea.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the above comment -- how is having `coffee-script` a dependency any different than having `underscore` as a dependency?

Comment: Underscore is a library, whereas CoffeeScript is a compiled language. You need a library's functionality at runtime. With a compiled language you don't (necessarily). All you need is the resulting code. (If it were an interpreted language you *would* need functionality at runtime.)

Comment: CoffeeScript is not a *compiled* language, it's a transpiled language. The difference is substantial: an optimizing compiler adds value to the compiled code. There is no *added* value to post-‘compilation’ JavaScript; only lost information (and thus lost value.)

Comment: (I know the current JavaScript community opinion-trend is against me on this one; but I stand by my opinion.)

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE - I thought it was the opposite. Coffeescript is like "shorthand". On compilation, it writes a bunch of boilerplate stuff for you.